# magento 2 edit customer HTML print order

Tags: magento-2.1, invoice, print

In the client `dashboard>My Orders>View Order` there is a `print order` option.

The file `vendor\magento\module-sales\view\frontend\templates\order\items.phtml` generates the output.  But any changes I make to this file changes all pages using the file.  Can I create a file so that only the print order url ( generated by `<?php  echo $block->getPrintUrl($_order) ?>`) will use its own file?

Or can I create a new link to a new file so I can edit just the print order output?

Answer (score 0):

in a template .phtml are hooked with blocks.
If you need it for some specific page then the way suggested is 
1. In layout handle add a new block.
2. Associate a .phtml 
3. remove block.

with this in mind now copy existing .phtml and create a new .phtme with needed specific changes.
So find out the handle for the URL you want changed layout and use above provided hints.

Comment: What is the handle for the URL?  The url is <?php  echo $block->getPrintUrl($_order) ?>